# Wie ist die korrekte Anrede für 3 Personen, wenn man nur von zweien den Namen kennt?

Tags: salutation

Ich muss eine geschäftliche E-Mail schreiben.

Zwei Personen sieze ich und kenne die Nachnamen.
Diese beiden Personen würde ich normalerweise anreden mit
Guten Tag Frau x, guten Tag Herr y,

Die dritte Personen hat aber leider eine allgemeine E-Mail-Adresse office@firmenname.de und hat ihre E-Mails an uns mit dem Vornamen unterschrieben.

Nun muss ich allen dreien zusammen eine E-Mail schreiben.
"Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren" finde ich unpassend, da dies viel zu unpersönlich ist für die Personen, die ich mit Namen kenne.

Was wäre eine gute Anrede?

Comment: Sehr geehrte ... war mir schon immer viel zu förmlich und geziert, und schon ein halbes Jahrhundert vor facebook empfand ich Floskeln wie hochachtungsvoll ... und ihr ergebener ... als unpersönlich und schreibe stets  “mit freundlichen Grüssen”, und in der Anrede statt “sehr geehrte” schreibe ich “ liebe”. Hört doch endlich auf mit diesen alten Zöpfen. Der Sprache tut ihr keinen Abbruch und bei den Empfängern rennt ihr offene Türen ein. Darum, wie wärs mit: (s. meine Antwort)

Comment: Würdest du alle drei einzeln anreden "Guten Tag Frau x, guten Tag Herr y, guten Tag Herr z", wenn du den Namen des Dritten kennen würdest? Würdest du auch alle einzeln anreden, wenn du fünf Empänger hättest?

Comment: Wie wärs denn eigentlich einfach mit: **Guten Tag** ???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In einer geschäftlichen E-Mail ist die Anrede wie in klassischer Briefform zu setzen. Ich schlage vor:

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, sehr geehrte Frau X, sehr geehrter Herr Y,

oder wenn im An-Feld auch Du-Bekannte angeschrieben werden:

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, liebe Anita, lieber Axel,

Comment: Ich finde, die "Sehr geehrte"-Anrede passt gut bei Firmen in sehr traditionellen Bereichen (z.B. Amt,  Steuerberater). Wenn mir das in unserer Branche jemand schreibt, dann denke ich "der ist wohl an die 60 Jahre alt und geht bald in Rente". Daher würde ich dies in einem normalen Brief in unserer Branche nie wählen. Aber in dem Sonderfall finde ich es gut, weil alles andere noch unpassender klingt.

Comment: Wenn ich denke, wie oft ich hier schon gelesen habe, etwas wirke gestelzt oder veraltet ... wenn etwas, dann dieses “sehr geehrte” und womöglich noch “mit vorzüglicher Hodchtung”

Answer (score 1):

1. Liebe Freunde
2. Liebe Kunden
3. Liebe Geschäftsfreunde
4. Liebe Geschäftspartner

aber warum nicht einfach ein fröhliches **”Hallo”** ???

Comment: Alles nur Männer?

Comment: Nein. Frauen sind und waren immer mitgemeint, ausser bei einer  Einladung zu einem Herrenabend!  Kunden und Kundinnen mag ja noch gehen, aber Geschäftsfreunde und Geschäftsfreundinnen ...?  Du kannst gerne konsequent auch immer nur die weibliche Form verwenden, davon ausgehend, dass die Männer mitgemeint sind. Da dies ja deine Bekannten sind, werden sie das schon verstehen.

Comment: Mit "liebe Geschätzsfreunde", wenn damit auch Frauen angesprochen sind, schießt man sich in vielen Firmen und Behörden in Deutschland ins Abseits. Ich dürfte das nicht in einer offiziellen Mail verwenden, daher -1.

Comment: im Abseits ist lebt es sich oft viel angenehmer ... :)
aber:
Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, liebe Anita, lieber Axel, (s.o.) finde ich auch o.k.

Comment: Ich finde es auch als Frau seltsam, wenn ich mit "Liebe Sandra" oder "Liebe Frau x" angesprochen werde. Das erzeugt eine Nähe, die ich im geschäftlichen Umfeld nicht angemessen finde. Außerdem hat der Schreiber nicht darüber zu entscheiden, ob ich lieb bin oder nicht.

Comment: Liebe Sandra, wenn ich schreibe  "liebe Sandra"  bedeutet das weder, dass ich dich liebe noch dass du lieb bist.   Es heisst einfach, das mir Floskeln wie "sehr geehrte" und "werte" ein Graus sind. Aber mit der Nähe ... da hast du recht. Ich möchte mich in aller Form davon distanzieren!

Comment: Nun, ich habe jeweils einfach geschrieben: Liebe Schulkommision! ;) Das war immerhin noch besser als der Lapsus, der einem übereifrigen, ultrakorrekten Kollegen passiert ist, als er sich um die Stelle eines Heilpädagogen bewarb und schrieb: Sehr geehrte Schulkommissionmitglieder und sehr geehrte Schulkommissionsmitgliederinnen.

Wie wärs denn eigentlich einfach mit: Guten Tag.